# Arch CPU temperature much higher than on Debian

Tags: debian, arch-linux, temperature

I switched to Arch Linux from Debian/Crunchbang and noticed much higher temperature.

It's almost the same configuration: openbox, etc and Arch runs with 57-70 °C but Debian works with 43°C - 50°C

I really like Arch, but I can't fix it, my touchpad gets really hot.
It's something with software, because wheezy was cold enough for comfortable work.

Comment: Is this the temperature while idle? If so, Debian probably set up some powersave feature which Arch hasn't.

Comment: this is temperature while webbrowsing (firefox) and geany editor - (zero flash)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that you have a variable frequency processor which is set to "ondemand" under Debian and "performance" under Arch.

You can modify these directly by writing new settings into `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`, using a command like `cpufreq-set`, or a GUI like `indicator-cpufreq`.

Comment: Its probably something else, in Arch I am using cpupower, and there are ondemand and performance profiles and I am using ondemand, this is result of cpupower frequency-info http://pastebin.com/pMpCAKjP

Comment: I'd look at the GPU next.

Comment: my notebook doesnt have nvidia-optimus, maybe I should disable somehow intel hd graphics and use only nvidia gpu, is this possible ?

Comment: @robinloop well, if you want it to run cooler, you probably actually want to use only the Intel graphics.

Comment: I tried Antergos, and there is much lower temperature, so My arch needs some configuration yet, but I cant figoure out, what it needs